# Iteration of function

Tags: function-construction

May I ask how can we create iteration function using the previous data that was imported and calculated. I have tried using {i, ndata}, on the equation function but it wasn't working.

```
Data1 = Table[{rawdata[[i, 4]], rawdata[[i, 5]], rawdata[[i, 6]]}, {i, 
ndata}] // MatrixForm
```

> -119250, -96272.3, 99360.9
>   -101295, -101074, 81934.5
>   -78703.3, -91442, 62798.3
>   -4002.85, -15345.5, 3604.86
>   -29904, -42238, 23428.3
>   49070, 29595.8, -33869.8

I would need to input this values at Wk1 {X,Y,Z} into this first equation.  Initial location Q0={0,0,0}, Q1 will have the new calculated position in {X1,Y1,Z1}

```
Q1= Q0 +Wk1*Δt (Equation 1)

Q2= Q1 +Wk2*Δt (Equation 2)

Qn= Qn-1 +WknΔt (Equation n, n=ndata points)
```

`Δt=1/200` constant variable

Are there any short function that I can create an iteration function calculate all 433 ndata points, based on the raw data input or do I have to break down {x,y,z} into an individual matrix: {x}, {y} and {z} to perform the iteration function.

Appreciate your advice. Thank you.

JL.

Comment: applying `MatrixForm` to `Data1` is likely a problem (Though you never use `Data1` in the remainder of the question..). Do `Data1=Table[...] ; MatrixForm[Data1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just as example define:

```
rawdata = RandomReal[1, {100, 3}];
```

Then you can write it recursively as:

```
func[data_, 1] := G0 + dt WK[data[[1, 1]], data[[1, 2]], data[[1, 3]]];
func[data_, n_] := 
 func[data, n - 1] + dt WK[data[[n - 1, 1]], data[[n - 1, 2]], data[[n - 1, 3]]]
```

Giving:

```
func[rawdata, 3]
```

> G0 + dt WK[0.803669, 0.697727, 0.677939] + 
>    2 dt WK[0.977735, 0.53124, 0.76784]

Comment: Thank you Fabian. I will give it a try.

Comment: Hi Fabian 
I have try it using your method. However, the iteration did follow the exact method. 

Here is my code: 
                                                                                       
In[692]:= func[ndata, 1] = 0 + DIMU1X[[1]]*Deltatime // N

Out[692]= {-0.59625}

In[694]:= func[ndata, 2] = func[ndata, 1] + DIMU1X[[2]]*Deltatime // N

Out[694]= {-1.10273}

In[695]:= CheckingTheta2 = Theta1 + DIMU1X[[2]]*Deltatime // N

Out[695]= {-1.10273}

In[699]:= 
func[ndata, i] = 
  Table[func[[ndata - 1, i]] + DIMU1X[[i]]*Deltatime, {i, ndata}];


Thank you.

Comment: +1 for mind-reading :-)